# how to keep selected value in combobox

Tags: php

how can i keep the selected value on combobox after i selected item on that combo. the combo has been connected with db. after i choose the value, then the value is gone, but i need to keep that value on combobox field

this :

```
<td>No SBM</td>
  <td>
    :
    <select name="sbm_muat" id="sbm_muat" onchange="submit();">
     <option value="">Pilih</option>
    <?
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sbm_muat");
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>
      <option value="<? echo $res[no_sbm];?>" <? if($_POST[no_sbm]==$res[no_sbm]){ echo "selected";}?>><? echo $res[no_sbm];?></option>
    <? }?>
    </select>
    <? 
    $sbm_muat=$_POST[sbm_muat]; //dari combo

    $que=mysql_query("select * from sbm_muat, customer, truck, driver, jns_pengiriman where customer.cust_code=sbm_muat.cust_code and truck.no_pol=sbm_muat.no_pol and jns_pengiriman.kd_jns=sbm_muat.kd_jns and driver.kd_driver=sbm_muat.kd_driver and no_sbm='$sbm_muat'");
    $rq=mysql_fetch_array($que);

    $kini=date("Y-m-d");


    ?>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the  [selected](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) property

```
<select name='myComboBox'>
    <option value='myValue' selected >my value</option>
</select>
```